# How to properly connect the Denoise node in Compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-passes, denoise

After enabling *Denoising Data* pass, there are now two image outputs:

- *Image*
- *Noisy Image*

Which should I use with the *Denoise node*? [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/filter/denoise.html) doesn't cover it.

[image]

Comment: Note that the options to enable denoising have moved in 2.9 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwowD.png

Comment: Thanks for the update, and also for improving the answer :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **Noisy Image** output is meant for the **Denoise** node.
But with very low samples, the *Image* output may give better results.

**Image output**

- this output comes pre-denoised by the [Internal denoiser](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html), if it's enabled
- this may lead to some lost detail if it's then denoised egain

[image]

**Noisy Image output**

- this is the intended output for the *Denoise* node
- the output has been [Despeckled](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/despeckle.html) to remove fireflies
- however this may cause bad shadow artifacts for extra low sample counts

[image]

<sub>Further Reading:</sub>
<sub>[Denoise node in Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/filter/denoise.html)</sub> 
<sub>[How to use Intel denoiser in Blender](https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-intel-denoiser-in-blender/)</sub>
<sub>[Blenderartists.org discussion from Aug 2019](https://blenderartists.org/t/big-denoise-test-intel-open-image-denoise-vs-others/1175114/120)</sub>
<sub>[intel openimage denoise](https://www.openimagedenoise.org/)</sub>