# Pixelated render output, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

Dear blender community,

So I'm pretty new to blender and general 3d creation and now I rendered my first good project but It has many point where the pixels doesn't belong to or the color of them isn't matching. I can provide a picture for that too. Would be greate if someone could help me. I can provide any additional information if needed. You can see the pixels mostly on the table and at the plant. I could remove some of them when I added another light that directly lights in the room but I don't really want that to be there because the picture is too bright then.
Thanks for helping!

[image: Lighting i used]

[image: Render]

Comment: Hello :). Please take screenshots using your [system built-in tools](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/), and upload images directly into the post. This will improve your chances on getting an answer :).

Comment: Yes, sure I'm new to this community here, thanks for the info I'll change that in some minutes. Need to render that again✌

Comment: hey, no this didnt help much, but thank you! i'm happy over every thing that could help. I'm also trying to fix it myself, maybe i finde the right settings :)

Comment: The settings of the linked question will solve it (there is nothing more to say), you just have to *read it*. In short: I suggest to bump up the samples to at least 1000, use a better image texture for the floor and only use the denoiser in the compositor: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173760/how-to-properly-connect-the-denoise-node-in-compositor/173761#173761

Comment: Okay thanks, I already use 1000 samples, I'll make some better textures. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From what I see and understand from your description, you are seeing something pretty common when using the Cycles renderer: Noise. (The bright pixels are sometimes referred to as "fireflies")

There are several ways of reducing this effect:
1) Try a higher sample count in the "render" setting [image: Samples setting]

2) Use one of the denoise options, for example this one: [image: Denoise]

3) Switch to Eevee Render Engine: [image: Eevee]

Comment: Thanks for your help but this didnt change much. I tried the evee render that looks pretty good but it isnt rendering my backlight material for cycles renderer. maybe you cloud tell me what i need to change in denoising to make increase it. just the strentgh? and im using 1000  as my rendersample but isnt really getting better. i appreciate your greate help!

Comment: ok nvm i need to wait till its rendered completly i didnt know its denoising at the end, ill share my result when its finished