# Why is my eevee render turn gray?

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

When I render a single image in Blender 2.83 with eevee or cycle it does it without any problem

[image: Image render]
But when i render an animation with eevee either in png (frame by frame) or in matroska (mp4) the result is always gray.
the colors of the letters on the right side move using
AnimAll add-on, I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *Compositing* enabled *(Properties Area > Output Properties (Printer Icon) > Post Processing)* but your *Render Layer* node in the *Compositor* is not connected to anything:

[image]

Either just turn off *Compositing* **or** enable all the passes used for denoising (Normal, Diffuse Color) and connect them properly. Read: [How to properly connect the Denoise node in Compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173760/how-to-properly-connect-the-denoise-node-in-compositor)

[image]