When animation is rendered, outputted frames are transparent
I'm trying to render a pretty small model with a camera moving around, viewing it from different angles. However, when I go Render -> Render Animation, my animation does not render, instead a transparent window. I'm new to blender, so I'm not sure what the cause is. I got my friend to test the render on his computer, and it was the exact same. Rendering an image also just outputs a transparent PNG.
Here's what Blender looks like while it's rendering:

The outputted frames are just transparent PNGs, so I won't upload them.
My computer is plenty powerful enough, running Arch Linux with Hyprland.
My friend's computer is even better, running Windows 11.
We're both running the latest version of Blender and latest OS updates. I tried running Blender in verbose mode using the terminal, but no errors related to this issue came up.
EDIT: Based on more information given to me, here's a couple more bits of information. I'm still very new to Blender, so if more information is needed please tell me!
My compositing section is completely empty, with no way of adding anything, because all the options are greyed out. I've tried the other in built rendering engines and they both produce the same result.
My lights seem to be fine and my cameras do point at the model.
If you need some more information, please tell me!
If you want, here's a link to download the project file if you've got time https://s.opnxng.com/download/2bdfb3d9855e00d4/#kMsE7UsPruIcGweY8e2clQ (this goes to a file sharing service)

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is not answerable at the moment for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by some accompanying screenshots with the [edit] button under the question. Editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Also please see the threads https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200828/when-rendering-an-image-the-output-is-grey and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181686/why-is-my-eevee-render-turn-gray to see if they answer your question. If they don't answer your question, then make sure to specify why and provide your setup, then we can reopen.

Thank you for the update. You have to untick Sequencer at the bottom of Output Properties

Under Output Properties > Post Processing, untick Sequencer which is used for Video Sequencer.


Thank you so much! This worked perfectly!

No problem. I just realized there is already this same answer in "possible cause #4" of this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53633/142292 so I closed your question as duplicate.

@Maxwell Just be aware: yes, disabling the Sequencer in Post Processing helps in this case when there are strips in the video sequencer. The only question remaining is: why are there strips? Are they there for a certain purpose? If so, they will not be used when you disable the Sequencer. If they are accidentally there and not really needed, they could probably also be deleted and then there is no need to disable the Sequencer. Only to keep cause and effect in mind.

@GordonBrinkmann Yes that is correct. Can you edit in this info into the answer or I edit it into it and then delete the comment? I mean like add an explanation of what is causing the problem (which is the clips in the sequencer) and the proper fix depending on what the OP intended, if they wanted to render what was in sequencer or the Timeline, well apparently he wanted to render what was in the timeline.
