# Not enough connectors in Render Layers node

Tags: compositing-nodes

I made models of series of glass chess pieces in Blender.  I want to use Compositing to add in a Denoise node, but the Render Layers node does not have a Noisy Image connector, it just has Image, Alpha, and Depth.

In Blender Guru's tutorial on Materials, his Render Layers node has all four of those connectors, plus a bunch of OTHERS as well.  How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: This could help: [How to properly connect the Denoise node in Compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/173760/78972)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable *Denoising Data* under *Scene Tab > Passes.*
Then your compositor will include all needed denoising passes.

Keep in mind, Denoising data are enabled for *each render layer* separately.

[image]

Comment: I have Denoising Data enabled, but my Render Layers node still only has Image, Alpha, and Depth.  There must be something missing from my blender project.

Comment: Actually, I changed to a different render layer and it had all the connectors, and now I have a snazzy-looking render!

Comment: Hello :). Glad you made it work. Denoising is indeed enabled *per* render layer.