# Render Layers node doesn't have denoise sockets

Tags: compositing-nodes

When I am in Compositing, my Render Layers node only has three sockets: Image, Alpha, and Depth.  But it is supposed to have much more sockets based around denoising, namely Noisy Image, Denoising Normal, Denoising Albedo, Denoising Depth, Denoising Shadowing, Denoising Variance, Denoising Intensity, and Denoising Clean.  How do I get those to show up?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the *View Layer* panel > *Passes > Data*, you need to activate the *Denoising Data* option.

[image]

Comment: So you don't need to activate the Denoising option ? Or maybe you SHOULDN'T activate it ?

Comment: I thought you didn't need but I haven't tried it by the compositor yet

Comment: I just tried it with really low samples ; you definitively shouldn't use the integrated denoising if you plan to use the compositor denoising !

Comment: Hey @thibsert :). Yes, you shouldn't combine the denoisers. That's why Denoising Data even come with its own *Noisy Image* output. That's a render output without the internal denoiser applied. As mentioned [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/173760/78972)

Comment: Thanks for the link ! As mentioned, Blender Manual doesn't cover it... for now...