# I'm trying to use the denoise function, but the nodes aren't showing up on the render layers

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am very new to Blender, and I accidentally deleted the *Render Layer* box in the node display in compositor. I don't know how to get it back, and all my renders are either just pure black or pure white.

[image]

I found how to add it back via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, but that brings me back to the reason I ended up deleting it in the first place: I'm trying to use the *Denoise* function, but the nodes aren't showing up on the render layers. It only says *Image*, *Alpha*, *Depth* and *Noisy Image*, but last time I did it (following along a tutorial) there were more nodes in the render layer box that now are missing. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189790/render-layers-node-doesnt-have-denoise-sockets

Comment: https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-intel-denoiser-in-blender/

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to *View Layer Properties > Passes*.

Every pass is a new output:

[image]