# Where to find the "Depth" node in Compositing - Blender 3.5.1

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

There used to be *Image*, then *Alpha*, then *Depth*, then *Mist* in the outputs of the *Render Layers* node in Blender Compositing.

Now I can't find *Depth* anymore. Could someone help me find it, or tell me the new alternative?

*Depth*:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/compositing/types/input/render_layers.html

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202043/im-trying-to-use-the-denoise-function-but-the-nodes-arent-showing-up-on-the-r/202048#202048

Comment: Hello, that's weird because it seems to be here in 3.5.1, maybe in the View Layer panel > Passes >Data > make sure that the Z otpion is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Go to: *View Layer Properties > Passes > Data* and check the box labeled "Z". This tells Blender that you also want the depth data as output so the socket *Depth* will appear.

Comment: thank you so much. 
This is the first time I've asked a question on this site. I'm still getting the hang of it, but I'll get the hang of it. 
Thank you so much for your help