# How to control the paramaters for denoising in 2.9?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me how the new denoising system in Blender 2.9 works. In the old system you could tinker with the parameters. Apparently not anymore.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.openimagedenoise.org/ and https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-intel-denoiser-in-blender/

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly connect the Denoise node in Compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173760/how-to-properly-connect-the-denoise-node-in-compositor)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.