# Rendering multi-layer EXR using File Output node in Python

Tags: python, node-editor, .exr

I'm writing a multi-view synthetic dataset generator and I want to save my rendered images as multi-layer EXR. I have a basic Python script that loads a template file with the compositing nodes below, append an object and renders from different views by varying the camera position.

When I render a scene in Blender, I get the desired result: a multi-layer EXR image with denoised colors, raw normals and clipped depths. However, I cannot find a way to render to the File Output node in Python, since `scene.render.filepath` is different than `nodes['File Output'].base_path`. When I call `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)`, I get a multi-layer EXR that essentially ignores my output node and just uses the value in Output Properties. This is true even if I remove the denoising node.

Is there any way to render through the File Output node in Python? Is my Composite node actually correct? I need compositing because I want to use the denoiser to reduce render times. Both `scene.use_nodes` and `scene.render.use_compositing` are set to True in my code.

[image: Nodes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the path of the output node you would have to set [`OutputNode.base_path`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CompositorNodeOutputFile.html?highlight=base_path#bpy.types.CompositorNodeOutputFile.base_path). Make sure [`RenderSettings.use_compositing`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html?highlight=use_compositing#bpy.types.RenderSettings.use_compositing) as well as [`Scene.use_nodes`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=use_nodes#bpy.types.Scene.use_nodes) is enabled. Tested against the following node setup successfully:

[image]

```
import bpy, os

C = bpy.context

# Enable Post Processing and Use Nodes
C.scene.render.use_compositing = True
C.scene.use_nodes = True

# Get the File Output Node by name
out = C.scene.node_tree.nodes.get("File Output")

if out:
    # Set the output path of the node based 
    # on the regular path of the output
    out_dir = os.path.dirname(C.scene.render.filepath)
    out.base_path = os.path.join(out_dir, "multilayer_")
    # Call the render operator
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Related: [How to properly connect the Denoise node in Compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173760/how-to-properly-connect-the-denoise-node-in-compositor)

---

Rendering in headless mode works as well:

```
./Blender -b file.blend -P script.py
```

[image]
*Layer Contact Sheet node in Natron*

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I am doing and the file output node doesn't get used. All I get is an EXR with 10 different buffers in `/tmp/`. I should specify that I am running this from the command-line using `blender scene.blend --python your_script.py` and not from the Scripting interface, where you code works. I feel like this is a bug.

Comment: Works for me like a charm in Blender 2.92.0, added my results @Hubble

Comment: Somehow two copies are saved, one in `/tmp/` and one in my output directory. Not sure what was the issue before, but this is resolved. Thanks!